Analytic expression for $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \alpha^n t^{\rho^n}$, $\alpha, \rho \in (0,1)$?
Is there an analytic expression for $f(t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \alpha^n t^{\rho^n}$, $\alpha, \rho \in (0,1)$, $t>0$?
The sum converges since the first part is geometric and dominates while the second term goes to 1, but I'm curious if there is a closed-form expression for this.
I know that $f$ solves the functional equation $\alpha f(t^\rho) = f(t) - t$, but that doesn't get me much further.

No. $\phantom{\text{And don't give me names.}}$
